# Google Apps Script ElementCallback: "Error encountered: "parameter" is not defined."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a small Google Apps Script that will help users navigate and use a Google Spreadsheet. There's a small form they can fill out. Among other things, it will take them to a particular sheet.

However, the callback for the form does not appear to be working. I'm really not sure why. I lifted the the ServerClickHandler/ElementCallBack code from a tutorial that works for me (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VmEPo6Rkq4). I trimmed out the script and tried using different widgets and panels. Nothing seems to work. This is probably something stupid that I just can't see.

When I click the Submit button in the form this script creates, I get the following error:
"Error encountered: "parameter" is not defined."

At the end of my rope. Been debugging this for 3 hours. (Novice programmer -- please excuse my incompetence.)

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function createIncidentDialog() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Incident');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(3,2).setId('submissionGrid');

  var shortNameLabel = app.createLabel('Incident Code');
  var shortNameTextBox = app.createTextBox().setName('shortName').setId('shortName');

  var regionLabel = app.createLabel('Select Geographic Region');
  var radio1 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'North').setName('north').setId('north');
  var radio2 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Central').setName('central').setId('central');
  var radio3 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'South').setName('south').setId('south');
  var regionPicker = app.createVerticalPanel().add(radio1).add(radio2).add(radio3);

  var submitButton = app.createButton('Submit');
  var submitLabel = app.createLabel("Click!");

  grid.setWidget(0, 0, shortNameLabel)
   .setWidget(0, 1, shortNameTextBox)
   .setWidget(1, 0, regionLabel)
   .setWidget(1, 1, regionPicker)
   .setWidget(2, 0, submitButton)
   .setWidget(2, 1, submitLabel);
  panel.add(grid);
  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("writeIncident");
  submitButton.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  // assemble everything in app
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // show the app
  doc.show(app);

}

// this function responds to submit button
function writeIncident(e) {
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var shortNameValue = e.parameter.shortName;

  if (e,parameter.north == 1){
    var regionValue = "North";
  }
  else if (e.parameter.central == 1){
    var regionValue = "Central";
  }
  else if (e.parameter.south == 1){
    var regionValue = "South";
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(regionValue));

  return app.close();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a typo

```
if (e,parameter.north == 1){
    var regionValue = "North";
  }
```

Try replacing the comma with a dot.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I also ditched the radiobuttons because I can't seem to read out their values (and they're also not enforcing the only-one-can-be-active rule.)